# How do i grab a specific element from html with vba using a selenium wrapper

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

How can i call just the 8th cell of a table from html using vba with a selenium wrapper? I am trying to print the date of these impounds into cells in excel. Here is an example where the search has returned the vehicle being impounded 3 times with 3 different dates.

view-source: https://www.autoreturn.com/indianapolis-in/find-vehicle/results

I have tried a couple different variatons of `.Findelement` such as

```
Sheets("VinCheck").Cells(i, "D").Value = chromeDriver.FindElementByClass("input-item").Text
```

but nothing seems to be working. This just returns a seemingly blank value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo class selector of [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to specify the column number (`nth td` cell within a row)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SearchVin()
    Dim d As WebDriver, hTable As Object, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
    Dim headers(), vin As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Const URL = "https://www.autoreturn.com/indianapolis-in/find-vehicle/"

    vin = "1G4HD57287U218052"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL

        .FindElementById("vin").SendKeys vin     '<== vin

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        .FindElementByCss("[onclick='submitVin()']").Click

        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hTable = .FindElementByCss("table")  'use tag name of results table to target table
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing
        'do something with results
        Dim towDates As Object, towDate As Object
        If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
            Set towDates = .FindElementsByCss("table tr.results-row td:nth-of-type(9)")
            For Each towDate In towDates
                Debug.Print towDate.Text
            Next
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Results look like:

[image]

---

**Restricting row**

You can of course add another `nth-of-type` selector to restrict the row retrieved as well. Say you wanted the tow datetime for row 2:

```
table tr:nth-of-type(2).results-row td:nth-of-type(9)
```

[image]

Note that as I am using a class `"."` selector as well then I am limiting returned rows in the above selectors to exclude the header row.

---

**Using last-child:**

As the desired column is the last `td` cell in a row (last column), you can use a [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo class selector instead of `:nth-of-type` e.g.

```
Set towDates = .FindElementsByCss("table tr.results-row td:last-child")
```

and

```
table tr:nth-of-type(2).results-row td:last-child
```

---

**Single return value versus list:**

If you are expecting a single value then you apply the css selector with

```
.FindElementByCss
```

e.g.

```
.FindElementsByCss("table tr:nth-of-type(2).results-row td:last-child")
```

If you are expecting a list of values then you apply the css selector with

```
.FindElementsByCss
```

e.g.

```
.FindElementsByCss("table tr.results-row td:last-child")
```

---

**first-child selector:**

Also worth noting you have access to [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector, for example to grab first result row.

---

**Writing out entire table:**

If you want to write out the entire table I refer you to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205360/why-is-sendkey-enter-not-working-with-chrome-browser).

Comment: Thank you very much this is just what I needed. Also thank you for showing me selenium I have been messing around with it and it seems really useful!

Comment: It’s awesome isn’t it?